# Why "Max made me put this here"?

Tags: php, html, mediawiki

Every MediaWiki has a [load.php](http://bits.wikimedia.org/www.mediawiki.org/load.php).

If called without parameters it returns:

```
/* No modules requested. Max made me put this here */
```

As a curious programmer I wonder:

Why did he do this?

I am sure in a big project like this there is a good reason for it. Looks to me like it would be bad to return an empty file to an ajax query or something like it.

BTW: Normally it is called with parameters like this: `load.php?debug=true&lang=de&modules=user.options&only=scripts&skin=modern&user=pi&*`

Comment: Damnit Max... Who knows, humor?

Comment: Shhh.... don't ask too many questions, or Max will get you.

Comment: <ironic>Max was propably a great manager who read in a management book that never ever a file should be empty and should have at least a comment in it.</ironic> And he forced the programmer to add a comment and he wrote this inside the file.

Comment: LOL.. thats gotta be the funniest coding comment ever...:).. Tried posting to the original site??

Comment: I think the person who wrote this comment is Max. Sounds a lot like _"I know this because Tyler knows this"_.

Comment: I don't know much about media wiki but this file is probably there for historical reasons (old code that require load.php). If its an empty file, version controlling systems will probably exclude the file.

Comment: Incidentally, load.php is *not* just a file that contains the comment -- it's the main entry point to the module loader, and is full of code. It just *echoes* the comment if it's called with no parameters. It's not really a comment at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This message comes from ResourceLoader.php. In [the history](http://git.wikimedia.org/blame/mediawiki%2Fcore.git/e4bcbe722ebbe9a5e8409d9fb3e26dbd51c88ecc/includes%2Fresourceloader%2FResourceLoader.php) of the file, using [`git blame`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html), you can see the code was written by Roan Kattouw (RK) in [this changeset](http://git.wikimedia.org/commit/mediawiki%2Fcore.git/ef315d737e5225ef2d16b559b1ab03447f7a84c8). From the changeset comment:

> Make load.php output a comment explaining what's going on when no modules were requested rather than outputting nothing. Max made me do this because he hates blank pages

So, your answer is, because Max hates blank pages, and if you want to know more, you should ask Roan. My guess would be that it's a debugging aid; rather than staring at a blank page wondering why it's blank, at least you know that you did something that caused a module loader request to load nothing...

As @svick points out, there is also a link to the [code review](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:Code/MediaWiki/78200), including discussion of whether it's a good idea to mention Max at all. Mentioning Max was seen as a possibility to partially close [MediaWiki bug 20281](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20281), which notes that there aren't enough [Easter Eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)) in MediaWiki.

And that's why public repositories of open source software are cool :D

Comment: And some more discussion is [in the old code review tool](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:Code/MediaWiki/78200) (linked from the changeset page).

Answer (score 1):

It is just to know, whats going on.

If i browse the load.php file of my MediaWiki installation with my web browser and want to check if there are any errors, they may get displayed or leave me a blank page.

A blank white page indicates a PHP error which isn't being printed to the screen.

But if i see a comment thats similar to `/* No modules requested. Max made me put this here */`. i do know its alright

AND that is the reason, why they needed to diff it.